# why does select option always post last value in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form select box which is correctly populated with values from mysql table, but when it is posted, the value posted is the very last item in the table 'manutags', rather than the selected item shown in the box. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my logic?

```
<p class="formlabel cf text nobox">Tag Style  <!--popuplate with tag styles-->
<?$i=1;
    while($i<11){?>         
        <select class="man_sty <?$m='man'.$i++;echo $m?>" name="style_id">
        <?
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT man,style_id FROM manutags WHERE man_id = '$m'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
         <option value="<?=$row[1];?>"><?echo $row[1]?></option><!-- tag dropdown values-->
        <?}?>
        </select>
    <?}?>
```

HTML

```
<p class="formlabel cf text nobox">
Tag Style
<select class="man_sty man1" name="style_id_1" style="display: none;">
<option selected="" value="Kliktag">Kliktag</option>
<option value="RD2000">RD2000</option>
<option value="Button-R">Button-R</option>
<option value="SnappTagg">SnappTagg</option>
<option value="AutoEID">AutoEID</option>
</select>
<select class="man_sty man2" name="style_id_2" style="display: none;">
<option selected="" value="rototag">rototag</option>
</select>
<select class="man_sty man3" name="style_id_3" style="display: inline;">
<option selected="" value="Qwik">Qwik</option>
<option value="Zee">Zee</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Comment: do you want the the order should be in latest posted values

Comment: the value I want to post is selected, from the drop down box. This correctly populated with a number of style_id, but when posted the last item in the 'manutags' table is posted, even though it does not show in the selection box.

Comment: As far as i can understand, you are making 10 dropdowns. what do you want? Whats the problem? when the form is posted, does it show the value of the last dropdown only?

Comment: @Bhavik htere are up to 10 items in the dropdown, which works perfectly. the value posted does not show in the dropdown, it is always the very last item in the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

All your menus have the same `name="style_id"`. So when you submit the form, they all set `$_POST['style_id']`. Since there's only one variable with that name, you only get the last one. You need to give them different names so you can get the selection from each.

Try:

```
<select class="man_sty <?$m='man'.$i++;echo $m?>" name="style_id[]">
```

Then `$_POST['style_id']` will be an array containing the values of each selection.

Comment: Iv tried .......name="style_id[]" the menu now does not populate with any options.

Comment: That makes no sense. This change has nothing to do with the options.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out. Seems you forgot to change `name` of each select.

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $manId = "man" . $i;
    echo "<select class=\"man_sty {$manId}\" name=\"style_id_{$i}\">";
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT man, style_id FROM manutags WHERE man_id = '{$manId}'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $selected = 'selected';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$row[1]}\" {$selected}>{$row[1]}</option>";
        $selected = '';
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

Comment: this solution does not populate the dropdowns

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: style_id in F:\.......tags_by_user.php on line 11, lin11 is:
$style_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['style_id']);

Answer (score 0):

make your drop down name dynamic. for 10 drop down 10 different name. then pick up the value of dynamic drop down. think will give you required result.

Comment: can youm post a suggestion as to how I do that, and how do I then get the correct value from $_POST['style_id'];

Comment: yes. I can post. first you tell me where are you incrementing the value of $i in while loop.

Comment: if you are creating 10 drop down then 1) increament value of $i. 2)name="style_id<?php echo $i;?>" - use this name. 3) after submitting form execute for loop to pick the value. for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){echo $_POST["style_id".$i];}

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting 10 select boxes, but your question says "a form select box".  If you only want one, move the select tags outside the loop:

```
<p class="formlabel cf text nobox">Tag Style  <!--popuplate with tag styles-->
<select class="man_sty <?$m='man'.$i++;echo $m?>" name="style_id">
<?php
$i=1;
while($i<11){
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT man,style_id FROM manutags WHERE man_id = '$m'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
        <option value="<?=$row[1];?>"><?echo $row[1]?></option><!-- tag dropdown values-->
    <?php
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

If you actually do want 10 select boxes, then you probably want to use an array syntax for the parameters:

```
<p class="formlabel cf text nobox">Tag Style  <!--popuplate with tag styles-->
<?php
$i=1;
while($i<11){
    ?>
<select class="man_sty <?$m='man'.$i++;echo $m?>" name="style_id[]">
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT man,style_id FROM manutags WHERE man_id = '$m'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
        <option value="<?=$row[1];?>"><?echo $row[1]?></option><!-- tag dropdown values-->
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Then on the receiving end, you will receive an array in $_POST['style_id'] (assuming you are using method="post" in your form).

Comment: this solution does not populate the dropdowns. I do want 10 select boxes, but 9 of them have css class -> display:none depending on a previous menu.

Comment: What do you mean "does not populate the dropdowns"?  Please show an example of what you want the resulting HTML to look like.

Comment: I'm sorry I have tried to post the html generated, but the post keeps getting rejected because I can't format correctly

Comment: You have to indent code with four whitespace characters on every line.